# A recursion formula related to *Catalan numbers*

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, generating-functions, catalan-numbers

When I was working on a problem related to [*Catalan Number*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number), I deduced the following recursion formula:
\begin{equation}
a_{l,r}=a_{l-1,r}+a_{l-1,r-1}+a_{l-1,r-2}+\ldots+a_{l-1,l-1},\\
where \quad r \ge l \ge 1,\\
and \quad a_{1,r}=1.
\end{equation}
And I used another method to derive that:
\begin{equation}
a_{l,r}=\binom{l+r-1}{l-1} - \binom{l+r-1}{l-2},r \ge l \ge 1.
\end{equation}
But I don't know how to deduce the above formula of $a_{l,r}$ by directly using its recursion formula or by using [generating function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function). Any ideas?

Comment: For catalan no we have one variable only like $C_n$, how come you have two variables $a_{l,r}$

Comment: @Nilanjan If you set $l=r=n$, then $a_{l,r}$ is $C_n$. So I said this problem is related to *Catalan* but not *Catalan* itself.

Comment: Consider the [André's reflection method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number#Second_proof) proof of Catalan number, you can interpret your $a_{n+1,m}$ to be the number of paths from $(1,1)$ to $(n,m)$ that do not across the line from $(1,1)$ to $(n,n)$. Now, your recursion formula will be easily deduced.

Comment: @Paul your method is what I called "another method", which I used to deduce the above recursion formula.